# How to edit files "inline" from within the terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, editor

When you launch an editor, it replaces the space used by the terminal, and display the first line of your file on top, possibly followed by empty space if your file is a one liner.

Is there an editor which keeps the terminal display, and only renders the first line, and of course let you navigate downward to the place you want to edit, only moving replacing in the viewport one line at a time ?

Comment: You want to take a look at the `screen` utility: http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/how-to-split-the-terminal-into-more-than-one-view

Comment: kind of, but screen or tmux are is for permanent parallel sessions. I only need one session, I intend to close the session after editing.

Comment: Nothing speaks against using them that way.

Comment: If you want to "split" your terminal then do so. Do not look for an editor that allows you to do that, but look for a utility to split the terminal.

Comment: the `ex` editor may suffice. It is really a non-full-screen version of vi(m). Of course there is the impossible to use `ed` as well. The best explanation of `ex` is 3-4 chapters in the O'Reilly `vi` book so worth your trouble to get a copy of that. Also, as your use case isn't completely clear (to me), it's possible to configure `vi` session so that it uses a termnial's alternate screen to display, and when you exit the "data" screen (what ever was there before) is restored, with all traces of the edit session removed. Good luck.